# How to retrieve Address Book contact photo and display it in WebView?

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to access a contact's photo from the address book and display it in the HTML.

My application is based on IBM Worklight, which uses Cordova, so the app is based on HTML, CSS and JS.
I have managed to display entire contact list from Address book. But, I have no idea how I can load the contact photo.

I could load the contact photo in native, encode it with Base64Encoded
String and pass that to HTML. But, this approach looks really nasty.
If the user have like 200 contacts, the application gonna surely
crash.

I just want to load the contact photo of each contact from HTML by using contact id like we usually do in a native Android application.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier if you'll also mention how you have added the contacts as-is.

Comment: What I do is, I invoke a native function from javascript to get the list of contacts. And display the list in html. Native side sends the contact data to javascript. 

Your first link is suggesting to directly access the address book from javascript. How can I used that "Cordova-Plugin-Contacts" inside my Worklight project ? I already have a subclass of CordovaPlugin. Do I need to replace that ? Can I have multiple CordovaPlugin in a single proejct ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the below code in Worklight 6.2, I searched my address book for all contacts with "Adar" in their full name and inserted into the HTML their full name and photo.

This was tested in iOS, however should work similarly for Android. You may need to add the follow permission in android\native\AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

**HTML:** in the `BODY` tag of common\index.html

```
<div id="contacts">
</div>
```

**JavaScript:** contents of common\js\main.js

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter   = "Adar";
    options.multiple = true;

    var fields =  ["name","photos"];

    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

function onSuccess(contacts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        $("#contacts").append(
            "<p><b>Contact name: </b>" + contacts[i].name.formatted + "</p><br/>" +
            "<img src=" + contacts[i].photos[0].value + "/><br/><br/>"
        );
    }
};

function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError');
};
```